# Multiple rowHeight values in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can I make each cell a different height in a UITableView? How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just implement [`-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for your table view delegate, and return different heights for those cells.